# Remove Unwanted Font Files from Loading into WordPress Frontend

Tags: front-end, fonts

I've built a custom theme for a client and have two random font files being loaded into the frontend of the site.

How will I remove these, I'm guessing they are part of Wordpress core?

Both files are highlighted on the image below

[image: e u]

Comment: Check from where the files are actually loading from. Logout from the WordPress & check. Try function [wp_dequeue_style](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dequeue_style/)

Comment: WP Core itself doesn't load any frontend fonts. The initiator column says content.js and main.js are responsible, so I doubt there is a WP specific based solution to this. Track down where `main.js` and `content.js` come from and check their code

Comment: @TomJNowell Bizarrely there isn't a `content.js` file anywhere on my Mac and the `main.js` file is a file i've added without any reference to a woff.2 file even when you lick on the link in the network panel. At times Wordpress really is the pits.

Comment: WordPress doesn't include a `main.js` or `content.js` file, those aren't WordPress files, they'll have been added by your theme or your plugins ( or by another JS file ). You have the dev tools open so just hover over the filename and see what the URL is, or click through to find out